# Extra blank line before heading not immediately preceded by another heading

Tags: context, grid-typesetting

What I would like to obtain is an extra blank line before a heading if this heading is *not* immediately preceded by another heading. This is what I have so far:

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\showgrid

\setupwhitespace[line]

\setuphead
    [section]
    [style=\bfa,
     before=,
     after=,
     grid=none]
\setuphead
    [subsection]
    [style=\bf,
     before=,
     after=,
     grid=none]


\starttext

\startsection[title={Heading}]

\input ward

\startsubsection[title={Subheading A}]

\input ward

\input ward

\stopsubsection

\startsubsection[title={Subheading B}]

\input bryson

\stopsubsection

\stoptext
```

In this example an extra blank line should be inserted before "Subheading B" while the space between "Heading" and "Subheading A" should not be affected.

How can this be done?

**Edit:**

Added a paragraph between "Heading" and "Subheading A". The extra blank line should also appear just before "Subheading A". Any thoughts on how to automate this?

Comment: `\setuphead
    [section]
    [style=\bfa,
     before={\blank[disable]},
     aftersection={\blank[2*line]},
     grid=none]
\setuphead
    [subsection]
    [style=\bf,
     before={\blank[disable]},
     aftersection={\blank[2*line]},
     grid=none]` does what you want to do?

Comment: Almost! Imagine there's a paragraph between "Heading" and "Subheading A" (see edited code above). I would like the extra blank line to also appear right before "Subheading A".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your linked question is about LaTeX though.